# JavaScript/jQuery --> Run the function whose name matches the data string inside THIS clicked link

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

How to run the function whose `name` matches the data string inside `THIS` clicked link?

```js
// From line 0 to 36 there are uninteresting details which are ment to set up canvas. 

// The 2 functions corresponding to my question are on lines 47 and 115. 

// First function (line 47) counts up to 94%, and Second Function (line 115) counts up to 54%. 

// You need the line --> var sim = setInterval(progressSim, 40); <-- on line 102 to fire the function.



var ctx = document.getElementById('my_canvas').getContext('2d');
var ctx2 = document.getElementById('my_canvas2').getContext('2d');
var al = 0;
var start = 4.72;
var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
var ch = ctx.canvas.height;
var diff;

var greenPart = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 100);
greenPart.addColorStop(0, '#0f2596');
greenPart.addColorStop(1, '#0ea5e8');

var whitePart = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 100);
whitePart.addColorStop(0, '#fff');
whitePart.addColorStop(1, '#0e97df');


var width = 3;
var width2 = 1;


ctx2.save();
ctx2.beginPath();
ctx2.rect(-width, -width, 70 + width, 70 + width * 2);
ctx2.clip();
// Then we draw the left half

ctx2.beginPath();
ctx2.arc(35, 35, 45, 0, Math.PI * 4, false);
ctx2.fillStyle = '#fff';
ctx2.fill();

ctx2.restore();

// This is the First Function 

function progressSim() {
  diff = ((al / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10).toFixed(2);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);

  ctx.lineWidth = width;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#1c295c';

  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.font = "bold 19px Arial";
  ctx.fillText(al + '%', cw * .54, ch * .54 + 2, cw);



  // First we make a clipping region for the left half
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(-width2, -width2, 100, 100 + width2 * 2);
  ctx.clip();
  ctx.lineWidth = width2;
  // Then we draw the left half
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#d7ecf6";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(50, 50, 45, 0, Math.PI * 4, false);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.restore(); // restore clipping region to default

  // Then we make a clipping region for the right half
  ctx.save();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(50, -width, 50 + width, 100 + width * 2);
  ctx.clip();
  // Then we draw the right half
  ctx.strokeStyle = greenPart;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.arc(50, 50, 45, 4.78, diff / 10 + start, false);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore(); // restore clipping region to default
  // First we make a clipping region for the left half
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(-width, -width, 50 + width, 100 + width * 2);
  ctx.clip();

  // Then we draw the left half
  ctx.strokeStyle = whitePart;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(50, 50, 45, start, diff / 10 + start, false);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.restore(); // restore clipping region to default
  if (al >= 94) {
    clearTimeout(sim);
    // Add scripting here that will run when progress completes
  }
  al++;
}
var sim = setInterval(progressSim, 40);





// This is the Second Function 

function progressSim2() {
  diff = ((al / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10).toFixed(2);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);

  ctx.lineWidth = width;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#1c295c';

  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.font = "bold 19px Arial";
  ctx.fillText(al + '%', cw * .54, ch * .54 + 2, cw);



  // First we make a clipping region for the left half
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(-width2, -width2, 100, 100 + width2 * 2);
  ctx.clip();
  ctx.lineWidth = width2;
  // Then we draw the left half
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#d7ecf6";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(50, 50, 45, 0, Math.PI * 4, false);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.restore(); // restore clipping region to default

  // Then we make a clipping region for the right half
  ctx.save();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(50, -width, 50 + width, 100 + width * 2);
  ctx.clip();
  // Then we draw the right half
  ctx.strokeStyle = greenPart;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.arc(50, 50, 45, 4.78, diff / 10 + start, false);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore(); // restore clipping region to default
  // First we make a clipping region for the left half
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(-width, -width, 50 + width, 100 + width * 2);
  ctx.clip();

  // Then we draw the left half
  ctx.strokeStyle = whitePart;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(50, 50, 45, start, diff / 10 + start, false);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.restore(); // restore clipping region to default
  if (al >= 54) {
    clearTimeout(sim);
    // Add scripting here that will run when progress completes
  }
  al++;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px 30px;
  color: teal;
}
```

```html
<a href="" data="progressSim">one</a>

<a href="" data="progressSim2">two</a>

<div class="canvaswrap">



  <canvas id="my_canvas2" width="70" height="70"></canvas>

  <canvas id="my_canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>


</div>
```

When I click the given link (there are 2 links) I want to store its `data attribute` inside variable and fire the function whose name matches that stored data attribute string.

For example, when I click 2nd link I want to store its data attribute `progressSim2` inside variable and fire the function `progressSim2()`.

First function counts up to 94% whereas the Second function counts up to 54%.

**Below my attempt ( I am using jQuery):**

```
$(function () {


    jQuery('a').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

         var storedata = $($.attr(this, 'data'));

        jQuery("#canvas1").fadeIn();

    var sim = setInterval(storedata , 40);          

  });



});
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest way to your question, in my opinion: create a "mapping" object and call upon its properties:

```
var OBJECT_MAPS = {
  'dummy1': function () => {},
  'dummy2': function () => {}
}
```

Use it like this:

```
some_event_handler(item_name) => {
  // Check if function exists in map, and it is actually a function
  if (typeof OBJECT_MAPS[item_name] === 'function'){
    // A) If execution context doesn't matter
    OBJECT_MAPS[item_name](param1, param2, ...); 
    // B) If execution context matters (change "this" to required context)
    OBJECT_MAPS[item_name].call(this, param1, param2, ...)
  } else {
    console.error('Callback by name ' + item_name + ' does not exist'); 
  }
}
```

I would discourage using global functions bound to window object as this is generally considered a bad practice. Manipulating and overriding global objects is very easy from browser's console, so anyone would be able to change how your functions work. Always hide your functionality from bad people, even if it is inside javascript :)

Other ways to do this:

- Use switch statement to "switch" between function callbacks.
- Make your callbacks "event listeners". Emit events when item is chosen.

Also, User by name "Hikarunomemory" noticed incorrect usage of attr function in your code, please see his response.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare  you progressSim and progressSim2 methods globally. You  can call them like this:

```
window[$.attr(this, 'data')]()
```

or you can store link to them in another Object:

```
object[$.attr(this, 'data')]()
```

Comment: It's generally not a good practice to put functions in global scope - they can either override other existing functions, or be overridden themselves from browser's dev tools by malicious people.

Comment: I know but I try to provide  solution in  author's case

Answer (score 0):

`var storedata = $($.attr(this, 'data'));` is incorrect.

To get a attribute, you should use `$(this).attr('data')` or `$.attr(this, 'data')`

Then, set the functions as a global variable, and use `window['funcName']()` to execute the function.

Here's a simple demo:

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var storedata = $(this).attr('data');
  console.log(storedata)
  window[storedata]();
})

var progressSim = function() {
  console.log('execute function1')
}

var progressSim2 = function() {
  console.log('execute function2')
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px 30px;
  color: teal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" data="progressSim">one</a>

<a href="" data="progressSim2">two</a>

<div class="canvaswrap">



  <canvas id="my_canvas2" width="70" height="70"></canvas>

  <canvas id="my_canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>


</div>
```

As a side note,

> eval() is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed
>   with the privileges of the caller. If you run eval() with a string
>   that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running
>   malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your
>   webpage / extension. More importantly, a third-party code can see the
>   scope in which eval() was invoked, which can lead to possible attacks
>   in ways to which the similar Function is not susceptible.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Comment: It's generally not a good practice to put functions in global scope - they can either override other existing functions, or be overridden themselves from browser's dev tools by malicious people. However you noticed an error in attr usage so no downvote :)

Comment: @Felini Thanks for your further explain. The answer you provide is a better way.

Comment: @Hikarunomemory I tried to implement your soluntion https://jsfiddle.net/mtxg3ez2/46/  but I get "window[storedata] is not a function"

Comment: @Piotr You can set function one and two as `window.one = ...` and `window.two = ...`

Comment: @Hikarunomemory ...but only on first click

Comment: @Piotr There's no sim and sim2 in the function's scope.

Answer (score -1):

the function "eval" runs string as a code,
example:

```js
function progressSim(){console.log("sim is ok")}
eval("progressSim()")
```

Comment: Using eval is dicouraged as it disables a lot of optimizations performed by JS engines.